# Styling a bootstrap drop down nested in a button group

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I nested a drop down menu inside a group of buttons but I'm having a little trouble styling the drop down menu to look like the main buttons. It seems like there should be bootstrap classes to do this without using css?

1. I want the drop down items to show a dark background when hovered over, just like when the main buttons get hovered over. See pictures below
2. There looks to be some styling when the main buttons get clicked as well, no styling takes place when the drop down menu items get clicked.
3. I would like similar text in the drop down as the main buttons

I'm just trying to make things look consistent.

Here is my code with a partially working [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zxnw8245/) and some pics that show the button group with drop down I'm trying to style.

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">House</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Apartment</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Studio</button>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Other <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a>Park</a></li>
            <li><a>Beach</a></li>
            <li><a>Field</a></li>
            <li><a>BackYard</a></li>
            <li><a>FrontYard</a></li>
            <li><a>Other</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: button group]

no highlighting when hovering over drop down menu items.

[image: no highlighting]

Comment: In your fiddle I selected load jquery on load and that will make your fiddle be fully functional. When I do this It seems that there is a hover effect for the dropdown menu items that is darker.

Comment: Just pull in the right libraries and you'll be fine - here's a demo with the options checked. http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/zxnw8245/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown menu options are notoriously light.  If you want to adjust the shade of the hover effect, you can add your own CSS to match whatever theme you're using.

Here's how you'd do it for the default theme:

```css
.btn-group .dropdown-menu li:hover a {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  border-color: #ADADAD;
}
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippet

```css
.btn-group .dropdown-menu li:hover a {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  border-color: #ADADAD;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">House</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Apartment</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Studio</button>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Other <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a>Park</a></li>
      <li><a>Beach</a></li>
      <li><a>Field</a></li>
      <li><a>BackYard</a></li>
      <li><a>FrontYard</a></li>
      <li><a>Other</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add these to css file to get background color when hovering..

```css
a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#2E3D4C;
    font-weight: bold;
}
li a:hover {
    color:#2E3D4C;
    background-color:#C2E0FF;
}
ul.menu li ul {
    visibility:hidden;
}
ul.menu li:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
}
ul.menu ul li:hover {
    background-color:#6B8FB2;
}
li a:link {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    margin:1px;
}
```

Comment: btw sorry, this is pure css, not Bootstrap, so i guess for bootstrap you only need to to add   li:hover a { color: #2E3D4C; background-color: #C2E0FF;}  to your css

Comment: how can I check/verify my margin being off by 2px?

Comment: ( that space below "other" on your menu ) I had a same problem which I corrected with ul.meni ul {margin:-2px;} in css....